# Choose a tab in textmate 2

Tags: textmate

Choosing :

I use a European keyboard (french) and I can't use ⌘1, ⌘2 etc. to access a specific tab with TM2.

These shorcuts are used by the Finder to choose a Desktop (Space). 
In the Preferences System, I use the default keys : ^& , ^é to go to a Desktop (Mission Control). These shortcuts works perfectly but ⌘1, ⌘2 works also perfectly in the Finder to go to the Desktop 1 etc. In TM2 go to tab use ⌘1, ⌘2 but these shortcuts don't work for me in TM2. So I have two possibilities to switch between Desktops in the Finder and none in TM2 to switch between Tabs !!

**My question is how to modify the shortcuts in TM2 or in Finder ?**  I would like to be able to use ⌘1, ⌘2 (or a different shortcut) in Textmate to choice a tab (file) .

or **How to remove the shortcuts ⌘1, ⌘2 used by the Finder to go to Desktop?**

Switching :

A) Remarks about switching tabs in TM2
   I can switch between tabs with ⌘} and ⌘{ but I can also make a switch with ⌘⌥-> and ⌘⌥<-.
I think it's strange to have two different shortcuts to make the same action

B) Remarks about switching Desktops (spaces) in the Finder
  I can use ^-> and ^<-

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! It's bit unclear what you are actually asking for here. Please read [How to Ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for ideas to improve the question.

Comment: @patrix I modified my question : I want to use keyboard shortcuts to go to specific Tab when several files are open. I see two possibilities : modify something in the Finder or something in TM. And I think it's very strange to have two shortcuts for the same action in the Finder and in TM2.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Mission Control shortcuts in System Preferences:

[image]

Comment: No it's insufficient. In this case I have ^⌘1, ^⌘2 and always ⌘1, ⌘2. The Finder steals the keys. The problem is how to remove the shortcuts ⌘1, ⌘2 of the Finder. Another  possibility is to make some changes inside TM2. A last remark, on the french system the view options of the view menu in the Finder are ⌘⌥1-4 and not ⌘1-4.